# Getting a lot of underflows in GNU Radio. Why?

Tags: gnuradio, gnuradio-companion, usrp, uhd

I am trying to send a cosine signal from a USRP B210 with a carrier of 2.4GHz. I need this signal to be as high in frequency as possible, but if I exceed a sample rate of ~10M I start to get many underflows and the program stops responding when I try to stop the run.

I get the following error:

```
[WARNING] [MULTI_USRP] The total sum of rates (20.000000 MSps on 1 channels) exceeds the maximum capacity of the connection.
This can cause underruns (U).
UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU
...
UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUusrp_sink :error: In the last 750 ms, 1870 underflows occurred.
```

And here is the system monitor while running the program:

[image]

Does anyone know what could be happening?

At first I tried to use 60M, as this is the limit of the USRP. At this point the system monitor showed one core on 100% which I thought it was the problem, ut at ~15M no core its at full capacity and Im still getting underflows.

Also, I ran the benchmark given in https://kb.ettus.com/Verifying_the_Operation_of_the_USRP_Using_UHD_and_GNU_Radio :

```
[HIPPER@archFH examples]$    ./benchmark_rate --rx_rate 10e6 --tx_rate 10e6

[INFO] [UHD] linux; GNU C++ version 13.2.1 20230801; Boost_108300; UHD_4.5.0.HEAD-0-g471af98f
[00:00:00.000039] Creating the usrp device with: ...
[INFO] [B200] Detected Device: B210
[INFO] [B200] Operating over USB 2.
[INFO] [B200] Detecting internal GPSDO.... 
[INFO] [GPS] Found an internal GPSDO: GPSTCXO , Firmware Rev 0.929a
[WARNING] [GPS] update_cache(): Malformed GPSDO string: GPSTCXO , Firmware Rev 0.929a
[INFO] [B200] Initialize CODEC control...
[INFO] [B200] Initialize Radio control...
[INFO] [B200] Performing register loopback test... 
[INFO] [B200] Register loopback test passed
[INFO] [B200] Performing register loopback test... 
[INFO] [B200] Register loopback test passed
[INFO] [B200] Setting master clock rate selection to 'automatic'.
[INFO] [B200] Asking for clock rate 16.000000 MHz... 
[INFO] [B200] Actually got clock rate 16.000000 MHz.
Using Device: Single USRP:
  Device: B-Series Device
  Mboard 0: B210
  RX Channel: 0
    RX DSP: 0
    RX Dboard: A
    RX Subdev: FE-RX2
  RX Channel: 1
    RX DSP: 1
    RX Dboard: A
    RX Subdev: FE-RX1
  TX Channel: 0
    TX DSP: 0
    TX Dboard: A
    TX Subdev: FE-TX2
  TX Channel: 1
    TX DSP: 1
    TX Dboard: A
    TX Subdev: FE-TX1

[00:00:03.414528827] Setting device timestamp to 0...
[INFO] [B200] Asking for clock rate 40.000000 MHz... 
[INFO] [B200] Actually got clock rate 40.000000 MHz.
[00:00:03.850163910] Testing receive rate 10.000000 Msps on 1 channels
Setting TX spp to 2040
[00:00:03.878517475] Testing transmit rate 10.000000 Msps on 1 channels
UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUO[00:00:13.986586780] Benchmark complete.


Benchmark rate summary:
  Num received samples:     32224791
  Num dropped samples:      68048147
  Num overruns detected:    573
  Num transmitted samples:  79670160
  Num sequence errors (Tx): 0
  Num sequence errors (Rx): 0
  Num underruns detected:   16773
  Num late commands:        0
  Num timeouts (Tx):        0
  Num timeouts (Rx):        0


Done!
```

Comment: As mentioned in one comment, the problem was that I was using a USB 2.0 cable in the USB 3.0 port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [WARNING] [MULTI_USRP] The total sum of rates (20.000000 MSps on 1 channels) exceeds the maximum capacity of the connection.

As the warning says, you're trying to get more samples across your USB port than your USB standard allows you to.

This means that you're using a USB 2 port, or a USB 2-only cable to connect your USRP.

And we see that instantly verified in your output, as well:

> [INFO] [B200] Operating over USB 2.

So, reading output is crucial!

Comment: Yes, I wasnt sure if

[INFO] [B200] Operating over USB 2.

Meant it was an USB 2.0 since I tried all ports and always said the same, but one of them is supposed to be 3.0.

Anyway, I was using an USB 2.0 Cable, as you said. I will replace it with an USB 3.0 cable and update the post.